# Call to a member function quoteIdentifier() on null (This error occur when i load add form)

Tags: magento2, error

```
<?php
namespace FME\AdminUser\Model;
 
use FME\AdminUser\Model\ResourceModel\User\collectionFactory;
 
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $collection;
    protected $loadedData;
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param collectionFactory $userCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        collectionFactory $userCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $userCollectionFactory->create();
        //echo 123; exit;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
 
    public function getData()
    { 
        $users = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
       
            $this->loadedData[$user->getPostId()] = $user->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I load a form then occur this error